# Writing a random amount of random numbers to a file and returning their squares

Tags: python, math, file-io, python-3.x

So, I'm trying to write a random amount of random whole numbers (in the range of `0` to `1000`), square these numbers, and return these squares as a list. Initially, I started off writing to a specific txt file that I had already created, but it didn't work properly. I looked for some methods I could use that might make things a little easier, and I found the `tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile` method that I thought might be useful. Here's my current code, with comments provided:

```
# This program calculates the squares of numbers read from a file, using several functions
# reads file- or writes a random number of whole numbers to a file -looping through numbers
# and returns a calculation from (x * x) or (x**2);
# the results are stored in a list and returned.
# Update 1: after errors and logic problems, found Python method tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile: 
# This function operates exactly as TemporaryFile() does, except that the file is guaranteed to   have a visible name in the file system, and creates a temprary file that can be written on and accessed 
# (say, for generating a file with a list of integers that is random every time).

import random, tempfile 

# Writes to a temporary file for a length of random (file_len is >= 1 but <= 100), with random  numbers in the range of 0 - 1000.
def modfile(file_len):
       with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete = False) as newFile:
            for x in range(file_len):
                 newFile.write(str(random.randint(0, 1000)))
            print(newFile)
return newFile

# Squares random numbers in the file and returns them as a list.
    def squared_num(newFile):
        output_box = list()
        for l in newFile:
            exp = newFile(l) ** 2
            output_box[l] = exp
        print(output_box)
        return output_box

    print("This program reads a file with numbers in it - i.e. prints numbers into a blank file - and returns their conservative squares.")
    file_len = random.randint(1, 100)
    newFile = modfile(file_len)
    output = squared_num(file_name)
    print("The squared numbers are:")
    print(output)
```

Unfortunately, now I'm getting this error in line 15, in my `modfile` function: `TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface`. As someone who's relatively new to Python, can someone explain why I'm having this, and how I can fix it to achieve the desired result? Thanks!

EDIT: now fixed code (many thanks to unutbu and Pedro)! Now: how would I be able to print the original file numbers alongside their squares? Additionally, is there any minimal way I could remove decimals from the outputted float?

Comment: Shouldn't `exp = newFile(l) ** 2` be `exp = int(l) ** 2` ? (and `l` as a name is never good - `line` would be a much better name

Comment: Why don't you use [random.randint(0,1000)**2 for i in range(random.randint(0,1000))] ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put newlines after each int, lest they all run together creating a huge integer:

```
newFile.write(str(random.randint(0, 1000))+'\n')
```

(Also set the mode, as explained in PedroRomano's answer):

```
   with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(mode = 'w+', delete = False) as newFile:
```

---

modfile returns a *closed* filehandle. You can still get a filename out of it, but you can't read from it. So in `modfile`, just return the filename:

```
   return newFile.name
```

And in the main part of your program, pass the filename on to the `squared_num` function:

```
filename = modfile(file_len)
output = squared_num(filename)
```

---

Now inside `squared_num` you need to open the file for reading.

```
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    for l in f:
        exp = float(l)**2       # `l` is a string. Convert to float before squaring
        output_box.append(exp)  # build output_box with append
```

---

Putting it all together:

```
import random, tempfile 

def modfile(file_len):
       with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(mode = 'w+', delete = False) as newFile:
            for x in range(file_len):
                 newFile.write(str(random.randint(0, 1000))+'\n')
            print(newFile)
       return newFile.name

# Squares random numbers in the file and returns them as a list.
def squared_num(filename):
    output_box = list()
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        for l in f:
            exp = float(l)**2
            output_box.append(exp)
    print(output_box)
    return output_box

print("This program reads a file with numbers in it - i.e. prints numbers into a blank file - and returns their conservative squares.")
file_len = random.randint(1, 100)
filename = modfile(file_len)
output = squared_num(filename)
print("The squared numbers are:")
print(output)
```

---

PS. Don't write lots of code without running it. Write little functions, and test that each works as expected. For example, testing `modfile` would have revealed that all your random numbers were being concatenated. And printing the argument sent to `squared_num` would have shown it was a closed filehandle.

Testing the pieces gives you firm ground to stand on and lets you develop in an organized way.

Comment: Thanks unutbu. Pardon my amateur syntax errors. I'm still learning... question: when you return this temporary file, does it close automatically, every time? The rest seems pretty self-explanatory. Again, I appreciate it.

Comment: When you say `with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(...) as newFile`, or `with open(...) as newFile`, the filehandle `newFile` is *automatically* closed for you when Python leaves the `with`-block. If you did not want the filehandle to close, then use `newFile = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(...)`. But I don't recommend that here since there would be some other issues you'd need to handle: (1) remember to call `newFile.close()` yourself. (2) Call `newFile.seek(0)` to allow reading from the *beginning* of the file. See [this post](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm) for more on `with`.

Answer (score 2):

By default [`tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile`](http://docs.python.org/3.2/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.TemporaryFile) creates a binary file (`mode='w+b'`). To open the file in text mode and be able to write text strings (instead of byte strings), you need to change the temporary file creation call to not use the `b` in the `mode` parameter (`mode='w+'`):

```
tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(mode='w+', delete=False)
```

Comment: Thanks Pedro. Pretty easy to understand now.